# How to preform a relative complement query in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml, query-expressions

### Background (ie what the heck is a relative complement?)

[Relative Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement)

### What I'm trying to do

Let's say I've got a custom `Vehicle` entity that has a `VehicleType` option set that is either "Car", or "Truck".  There is a 1 to many relationship between Contact and Vehicle (ie. ContactId is on the vehicle entity).  How do I write an XRM query (Linq To CRM, QueryExpression, fetch Xml, whatever) that returns the contacts with only cars?

[image: Relative Complement Venn Diagram]

Comment: Certainly not in the CRM implementation of FetchXML. How are you trying to use this query? As a one-off workaround you could create a static Marketing List of Contacts then manage members using Advanced Find to add all Contacts with vehicles and then again to remove all Contacts with trucks, leaving only car-only owners. You could then easily run a query for Contacts who are members of this marketing list. But the list itself won't be dynamic and needs periodic updating.

Comment: Alternative would be using something like a workflow on vehicles to increment / decrement count of cars and trucks on the Contact, and query for cars>1 AND trucks=0. There are lots of reasons why this may not be very robust though.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question this seems like a pretty straight forward query to me.

Comment: @AdamV, I'm dealing with probably half a million records, so I'm not sure how efficient that will be.  I guess I could create a `HasTruck` flag on the contact that I update with a Create/Update/Delete plugin of the Vehicle Entity...

Comment: I guess I did misunderstand the question then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to order to perform a true Relative Complement Query you need to be able to perform a subquery.

Your query would basically say give me all the contacts with cars, and then, within those results, remove any contacts that have a vehicle that isn't a car.  This is what the SQL in @JasonKoopmans answer does.  Unfortunetly, [CRM does not support SubQueries](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crminthefield/archive/2013/01/14/dynamics-crm-2011-sdk-query-limitations-by-api.aspx).

Therefore, the only way to achieve this is to either perform the sub query on the client side, as I resorted to doing, or storing the results of what would be the subquery in a manner that can be accessed through the main query (ie storing counts on the contact entity).

You could theoretically do this "on the fly" by making a `SubQueryResult` entity that stores a `ContactId`, and `SubQueryId`.  You'd first pull back the contacts that have at least 1 car, and create a SubQueryResult record for each record, with it's contactId, and a single SubQueryId that is generated client side to tie them all together.

Then you'd do another query that says give me all the contacts that are in this SubQueryResult with this SubQueryId, that do not have any vehicles that aren't cars.

I could only assume that this wouldn't be any more efficient than performing the two separate queries and performing the filter client side.  Although with the new ExecuteMultipleRequests in the new CRM release, it may be close.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson - As the link in my answer states, it is not possible to perform a sub query in CRM.  And in order to perform a relative complement, a sub query is required.  There are work arounds that can be performed to eliminate the need for a sub query, but which work around is best, is entirely dependent on the exact scenario. I would put your exact scenario in a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

I’d prefer a modification of the proposal that AdamV makes above.  I can’t think of a way that you’d get this particular query answered using Linq to CRM, Query Expressions, FetchXML alone.  Daryl doesn’t offer what the client is, but I would suppose if Linq and Query Expressions were acceptable offerings, .NET is on the table.  Creating aggregate fields containing the count  of the related entity on the parent entity (contact in this case) offers more than the Boolean option.  If the query requirements ever changed to a threshold (more than X cars, less than Y trucks, between X and Y total vehicles) the Boolean options fails to deliver.   The client in this question isn’t known, but I can’t think of many (any?) cases where pulling all the records to the client on a set of 500K+ rows is more efficient than a the SQL query that CRM would make on your behalf against several integer fields with range clauses.

Upside:

1. Maintains client purity in Query approach
2. Simple client query
3. Probably as performant as possible

Downside:

1. Setups for Aggregate fields
2. Workflow or plugin to manage the increment and decrement of the aggregate fields
3. SQL Script for initial load of the aggregates.
4. Risk that aggregate fields get out of sync (workflow or plugin fails)

### Option 2:

If purity within the client isn’t essential, and .NET is on the table – skip the aggregate fields and the setup and just run SQL against the Views.  If you don’t want to work with the ADO.NET, a thin ORM like Dapper, Massive, or PetaPOCO can still give you an object model.  As Andreas offers in his comment on the OP’s first answer, it seems like something fairly trivial to do in SQL.

Sketching something from top of mind:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contact 
WHERE C.Contactid in (
    Select contactid 
    FROM Vehicle v 
    group by v.contactid , v.type
    having v.type = ‘Car’ and count(contactid) > 1 
) 
AND NOT IN (
    Select contactid 
    FROM Vehicle v 
    group by v.contactid , v.type
    having v.type <> ‘Car’ and count(contactid) > 1 
)
```

Upside:

1. Much less work
2. CRM Entities get left alone

Downside:

1. Depending on the client and/or the application mixing DataAccess methods is a bit kludgy.
2. Likely less performant than Option 1

### Option 3:

Mix and Match:  Take the aggregate fields from Option 1.  But update them using a scheduled SQL job (or something similar) with a query similar to the initial load job you’d need to write in Option 1

Upside:

1. Takes most of the work and risk out of Option 1
2. Keeps all of the performance of Option 1

Downside:

1. Some will see this as an unsupported feature.

Comment: @Daryl needs to solve it in CRM, not SQL. Sadly. And my suggestion is to solve it in a supported way, so it can be reused in on-line version. The neatest way would be to get the query expression working, because then one might adapt it to other problems.

Comment: @KonradViltersten is right in that I only have QueryExpressions, Odata, Linq to CRM, and FetchXml as possible tools for CRM online.  And unfortunetly your option 1 breaks down when you start dealing with more types of vehicles.  What if we add Bus, Tractor, Boat, Plane, Train, and Motorcycle in the future?  Now i have 8 counts to correctly increment on the contact entity...  But yes, it is an option, although with CRM's lack of a Transaction scope, impossible to guarantee correct and immediate results.

Answer (score 0):

I have resorted to pulling back all of my records in CRM, and performing the check on the client side since CRM 2011 doesn't support this via Query Expressions.

You could write two Fetch XML statements, one to return all contacts and the count of their vehicles, and another to return all contacts and the count of their cars, then compare the list on the client side.  But once again, you're having to return every contact and filter it client side.

Comment: I'll be doing something similar to this and I'm curious about it too. May I know how you concluded it wasn't doable? (In SQL, I think I could do that but in CRM, I get a little bit stuck.) In fact, if you un-check your own answer, I'll be happy to put a bounty on it.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson I'll unanswered it and open it up.  I'll look for the supporting site I found on Monday.

Comment: I've boutied the question. Hopefully, we'll get some more attention to it. What happens if there are no (worthy) replies), by the way? Do I get the rep back or do you get it for your first reply to your own post?

Answer (score 0):

It's not tested but how about this query expression? I'm linking in the *Vehicle* entity as an inner join, requiring that it's a *Car*. I'm assuming that the field *VehicleType* is a *String* because I'm a bit lazy and don't want to test it (I'm typing this hardcore style, no compilation - pure brain work).

Optionally, you might want to add a *Criteria* section as well to control which of the *Contact* instances that actually get retrieved. Do tell how it went!

Sorry for the verbosity. I know you like it short. My brains work better when circumlocutory.

```csharp
new QueryExpression
{
  EntityName = "contact",
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fullname"),
  LinkEntities =
  {
    new LinkEntity 
    { 
      JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner, 
      LinkFromEntityName = "contact", 
      LinkFromAttributeName = "contactid", 
      LinkToEntityName = "vehicle", 
      LinkToAttributeName = "contactid",
      Columns = new ColumnSet("vehicletype"),
      EntityAlias = "Vroom",
      //LinkCriteria = { Conditions = 
      //{
      //  new ConditionExpression(
      //    "vehicletype", ConditionOperator.Equal, "car")
      //} }
      LinkCriteria = { Conditions = 
      {
        new ConditionExpression(
          "vehicletype", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "truck") 
      } }
    } 
  }
};
```

EDIT:

I've talk to my MVP Gustaf Westerlund and he's suggested the following work-around. Let me stress that it's not an answer to your original question. It's just a way to solve it. And it's cumbersome. :)

So, the hint is to add a flag in the *Contact* or *Person* entity. Then, every time you create a new instance of *Vehicle*, you need to fire a message and using a plugin, update the information on the first about the creation of the latter.

This has several drawbacks.

1. It requires us to do stuff.
2. It's not the straight-forward do-this-and-that type of approach.
3. Maintenance is higher for every new type of *Vehicle* one adds.
4. Buggibility is elevated since there are many cases to regard (what happens to the flagification when a *Vehicle* instance is reasigned, deleted etc.).

So, my answer to your question is changed to: "can't be done". This remains effective until (gladly) proven wrong by presented alternative solution. Duck!

Personally, I'd fetch (almost) everything and unleash the hounds of LINQ onto it. But I'd do that without smiling nor proud. :)

Comment: Nope.  This will return all contacts with a car.  I want all contacts with only cars.

Comment: And congrats on teaching me the definition of circumlocutory, but I'd suggest removing this as an answer.

Comment: @Daryl Would you care to elaborate, please? In my ears it sounds like "I don't want X. I want X instead". What am I missing? I thought you wanted all the contacts with cars. (I'll remove the reply, of course, but I want to take another whack at it if I better understand the objective.)

Comment: I want a query that returns all of the contacts with only cars, and no other types of vehicles.  Your query returns contacts with at least one car, not taking into account that I don't want contacts with trucks.  @JasonKoopmans's SQL statement in Option 2 is a correct SQL representation of the desired records.

Comment: @Daryl Hmm... You mentioned that the *Vehicle* is a picklist (i.e. an optionset), so I assumed that having a *Car* and having a *Truck* are mutually exclusive options, meaning that having a *Car* makes it implied that there's no other kind of *Vehicle*. Let's me try to refine the query expression provided. It should be that hard to introduce the extra condition. (And *circumlocutory* is a nice, isn't it? I had to look up a Swedish word, very commonly used, and got **that**. Never seen it before myself, either...)

Comment: The contact can have multiple vehicles, but each vehicle can only have one type.  I can have a car, and a truck, but I can't have a car that is also a truck (although the El Camino came close)

Comment: @Daryl Did the update work for you? I see that the filter is set up to exclude the wrong type of vehicle. Did that work? 5 days left - then somebody needs to get +50 cool ones.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson The query above does not work.  If for example a contact has a car and a truck, the query will return it because it has a vehicle that is not a truck.  But it also has a truck and the query does nothing to restrict that.   (If you can guarantee that a contact will have at most one vehicle, then it works just fine. but that isn't what I'm asking.  I'm asking for all contacts that have only cars.)

Comment: @Daryl But there's an update. Doesn't `new ConditionExpression("vehicletype", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "truck") ` make any difference to restrictions?

Comment: @AndreasJohansson No, my comment took the change into account.

Comment: @Daryl I'm surprised and a bit disappointed. How is it possible that the *Vroom* being excluded when equal to *Truck*, still brings you the trucks? How are the *Vehicle* instances added to the *Contact* instance? A table?

Comment: Remember, we are not returning vehicles, we are returning contacts.  And your query says bring me all contacts who have a vehicle that isn't a truck.  If a contact has both a truck and a car, it will be returned because it has a a vehicle that isn't a truck.  But it also has a truck!  And as stated in question I only want contacts that only have cars.  I don't how to better explain it.

Comment: @Daryl It's not your explanation that's at blame. I just get too impatient and really want to help you. I've invested quite an effort into this question and I want those 50 reps, haha. I've asked a guy at work and he suggested something. When I get home, I'll make another edit to the reply. Hopefully the last one.

Comment: @Daryl This is my last attempt. Unwillingly, I'm trowing in the towel. Sorry, mate.

Comment: I agree with your Edit.  It can't be done with a single queryexpression, or fetchxml, or Linq to CRM call.  Doing so would require being able to perform some type of subquery, and as the link in my answer states, it CRM doesn't support it (outside of a direct SQL query which isn't possible in CRM Online).  So the closet you can come is doing extra work to store the relationship of contacts to vehicles within CRM, so that a sub query is not required.  And there are a hundred different ways to do this...